# window.open(url, name, features) under IE

Tags: javascript, html

This is regarding JavaScript method `window.open(url, name, features)`.
If the url is relative or under the same domain of the current page, the parameter `features` will be ignored by IE.

Example: http://statcomp.ats.ucla.edu/WebTools/JavaTools/popup.htm.

This happens in IE8/9 at least.
Why? Is there any workaround?

Thanks a lot, Xiao

Answer (score 2):

The only time you use `px` for a client side web thing is in CSS.

That should be: `height=400,width=400`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the first example is not good enough. The second is without `px`, but still IE fails...

Comment: I suggest you provide a link to a working version of your code and not to third party tutorials or ASP source that will generate the code you are actually asking IE to run.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the browser does respect the size, but the other properties are ignored as they don't have any value.

Use a value of `1`, `0`, `yes` or `no` for the properties:

```
width=480,height=200,scrollbars=1,dependent=1,resizable=1
```